# При редиректе из одной активити в другую отображается только карта, всего остального - нет

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

возникла проблема, у меня 2 активити с ямапам, при редиректе из одной в другую отображается только карта, всего остального - нет, при этом на первой активити все есть и работает, ниже приведу в пример 2 класса, которые использую. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

1

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserLocationObjectListener  {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private static final String GEOCODER_API_KEY = "123";
    private MapView mapView;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private UserLocationLayer userLocationLayer;
    public Point ROUTE_START_LOCATION = null;
    public Point ROUTE_END_LOCATION = null;
    private MapObjectCollection mapObjects;
    private DBClass DBClass = new DBClass();
    private DBHelper dbHelper;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        peremissionInternet();
        requestLocationPermission();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(!init) {
            MapKitFactory.initialize(this);
            init = true;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.getMap().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(new Point(0, 0), 14, 0, 0));

        //Стили!!!
        mapView.getMap().setMapStyle(style);
        mapView.getMap().setMapStyle(styleLand);

        MapKit mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance();
        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapView.getMapWindow());
        userLocationLayer.setVisible(true);
        userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(true);
        userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(this);

        mapView.getMap().addInputListener(il);
        mapObjects = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCollection();

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_info, R.id.nav_exit)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        start = findViewById(R.id.start_bottom);
        finish = findViewById(R.id.finish_bottom);

        Button go = findViewById(R.id.buttonGoSheet);

        go.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            DBClass = new DBClass();
            String hash = DBClass.getHash(HomeActivity.this);
            String url = URL_API_USERS +"/"+hash;
            String arg = "active=2";
            new Thread(() -> {
                if(HttpApi.put(url, arg) == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    showToast("Ожидайте пока приймут ваш заказ");
                    RedirectToDriver();
                    //вывод всплыувуающего окна
                }
            }).start();

        });

        TextView eco = findViewById(R.id.eco);
        TextView middle = findViewById(R.id.middle);
        TextView business = findViewById(R.id.business);

        //добавить в бд класс заказа
        eco.setOnClickListener(view -> Class = 1);
        middle.setOnClickListener(view -> Class = 2);
        business.setOnClickListener(view -> Class = 3);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void peremissionInternet(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.INTERNET")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.INTERNET"},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectAdded(UserLocationView userLocationView) {
        userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.5)),
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.83)));

        userLocationView.getArrow().setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(
                this, R.drawable.user_location));

        CompositeIcon pinIcon = userLocationView.getPin().useCompositeIcon();

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "icon",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.user_location),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(0f)
                        .setScale(1f)
        );


        userLocationView.getAccuracyCircle().setFillColor(Color.BLUE & 0x99ffffff);

    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectRemoved(UserLocationView view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectUpdated(UserLocationView view,  ObjectEvent event) {

    }

    private final InputListener il = new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onMapLongTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {

        }
    };


    public void showToast(final String toast)
    {
        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    }

}
```

2

```
public class GoActivityUser extends AppCompatActivity implements UserLocationObjectListener, DrivingSession.DrivingRouteListener {

    private String hash;
    private DBClass dbClass = new DBClass();
    private UserLocationLayer userLocationLayer;
    private MapView mapView;
    private HashMap<String, Object> geolocation;
    public DBClass DBClass;
    private DrivingRouter drivingRouter;
    private MapObjectCollection mapObjects;
    private DrivingSession drivingSession;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private Point ROUTE_START_LOCATION = new Point(59.945933, 30.320045);
    private Point ROUTE_END_LOCATION = new Point(59.945933, 30.320045);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        peremissionInternet();
        requestLocationPermission();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.go_activity_user);


        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapviewUserGo);
        mapView.getMap().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(new Point(0, 0), 14, 0, 0));
        MapKit mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance();
        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapView.getMapWindow());
        userLocationLayer.setVisible(true);
        userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(true);
        userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(this);

        drivingRouter = DirectionsFactory.getInstance().createDrivingRouter();
        mapObjects = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCollection();

        try {
            hash = dbClass.getHash(this);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("hash", e.getMessage());
        }

        submitRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onObjectAdded(@NonNull UserLocationView userLocationView) {
        HashMap<String, Object> geo = new HashMap<>();
        userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.5)),
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.83)));

        userLocationView.getArrow().setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(
                this, R.drawable.user_location));

        CompositeIcon pinIcon = userLocationView.getPin().useCompositeIcon();

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "icon",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.user_location),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(0f)
                        .setScale(1f)
        );

        userLocationView.getAccuracyCircle().setFillColor(Color.BLUE & 0x99ffffff);

    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectRemoved(@NonNull UserLocationView userLocationView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectUpdated(@NonNull UserLocationView userLocationView, @NonNull ObjectEvent objectEvent) {

    }

    private void submitRequest() {
        DrivingOptions drivingOptions = new DrivingOptions();
        VehicleOptions vehicleOptions = new VehicleOptions();
        ArrayList<RequestPoint> requestPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        requestPoints.add(new RequestPoint(
                ROUTE_START_LOCATION,
                RequestPointType.WAYPOINT,
                null));
        requestPoints.add(new RequestPoint(
                ROUTE_END_LOCATION,
                RequestPointType.WAYPOINT,
                null));
        drivingSession = drivingRouter.requestRoutes(requestPoints, drivingOptions, vehicleOptions, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrivingRoutes(@NonNull List<DrivingRoute> list) {
        for (DrivingRoute route : list) {
            mapObjects.addPolyline(route.getGeometry()).setStrokeColor(17466623);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrivingRoutesError(@NonNull Error error) {
        String errorMessage = getString(R.string.unknown_error_message);
        if (error instanceof RemoteError) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.remote_error_message);
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.network_error_message);
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void peremissionInternet(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.INTERNET")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.INTERNET"},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        }
    }
}
```

ВОЗМОЖНЫ СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИЕ ОШИБКИ, У МЕНЯ ИХ В КОДЕ НЕТ, СОКРАЩАЛ КАК МОГ, ЧТОБЫ БЫЛО ПРОЩЕ ПОНЯТЬ СУТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ

Comment: А в поддержку не писали? Они не всегда быстро отвечают, но помочь могут.